# What is the correct linguistic term for names that are statements?

Tags: names, linguistics

What is the linguistic term for names, that are actually statements?  examples for this type of names are ancient egyptian names such as [Neferkare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neferkare), meaning *Perfect is the Ka of Ra*, or Indigeneous American names, such as [Sitting Bull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitting_Bull).

Comment: Also common in Hebrew names, e.g. Tobias ([God is good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobias)) and Elizabeth ([variously given as God is an oath or God is abundance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_(given_name))).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel) calls them "symbolic names", but I doubt it is a linguistic term.

Comment: @fev: Indeed, there must be a more specific, scientific (and presumably latin or greek)  term for these type of names - that's what I am looking for.

Comment: "An aptronym, aptonym, or euonym is a personal name aptly or peculiarly suited to its owner." (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym).  Same source says "Marilyn vos Savant, American columnist who has been cited for having the world's highest-recorded IQ (savant)" But I'm not sure from your question as to whether you want an *apt* name that is a statement.

Comment: How is "Sitting Bull" a statement? It seems to be more of a description (which seems to be a common style of Native American names).

Answer (score 2):

***Theophoric names*** might be what you are looking for:

> ***A theophoric name*** (from Greek: θεόφορος, theophoros, literally "bearing or carrying a god") embeds the name of a god, both invoking
> and displaying the protection of that deity. For example, names
> embedding Apollo, such as Apollonios or Apollodorus, existed in Greek
> antiquity.
>
> Theophoric personal names, containing the name of a god in whose care
> the individual is entrusted (or a generic word for god), *were also
> exceedingly common in the ancient Near East and Mesopotamia*. Some
> names of theophoric origin remain common today, such as Theodore
> (theo-, "god"; -dore, origin of word compound in Greek: doron, "gift";
> hence "God's gift"; in Greek: Theodoros) or less recognisably as
> Jonathan (from Hebrew Yonatan/Yehonatan, meaning "Yahweh has given").

([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theophoric_name#targetText=A%20theophoric%20name%20from%20Greek,Apollodorus%2C%20existed%20in%20Greek%20antiquity))

Comment: I am looking for a more general term, that includes non-teophoric names, as well (as specified in the updated original question).

Comment: Well, you did edit the question after I answered in a way that made my answer no longer be valid.

Comment: Unfair, I know. Fortunately, answers can be updated as well :-)

Comment: Of mild interest: Nebuchadnezzar means "Nabu, watch over my heir".  Joshua means "The LORD is salvation." These are theophoric names that are also statements.

Comment: @rahaj: Yes, the list is amazing. I am actually grateful for the question, because I found the name of this phenomenon... It's quite common, from the biblical I/Emmanuel (God is with us) to the South-African Goitsione (God Knows) . Fascinating...

Comment: I checked the pre-edit question. It never asked for a term for names that come from a god. The only example happened to be theophoric, but the question itself was clear about what they're looking for.